# How do I move photos from a Lightroom collection to a folder, preserving order?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-5

In Lightroom 5, I have a collection that contains a bunch of photos in a carefully arranged order (User Order). I want to move these photos to a new folder, preserving the order.

How do I do this? If I select the photos in the collection, then create the folder, leaving checked the option to move the selected photos to the folder, the order is lost.

I tried first creating the folder, then selecting the photos to move and dragging them to the folder (rather than doing it as part of folder creation) but that doesn't work, either.

The only option I can see is to manually drag each photo to the folder, which is lame. Is there a better way?

Comment: Isn't a folder always sorted by name, date or some other property? I'm not aware of folders where you can manually sort the files. You could try renaming the photos in the user order first (`Library -> Rename photos`) with a sequence, then move them to a folder and sort them by name. If the filename starts with the sequence you will retain the user order (I think).

Comment: I find that I can manually drag the photos around in the folder, so they do support user order. I will try the rename trick the next time. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Bart, this worked. Just one thing, though — after moving the photos to the folder, the user order is messed up. I have to say View > Sort > File name, which you pointed out, but if I ever were to change the sort to User Order, I'll get back the messed up order. To fix this, I have to reset the user order to the file name, but choosing to sort by file name, and then dragging a photo somewhere else and then dragging it back to its original position. Then the user order is reset to the file name order.